# list[0] is bigger than list[1]. So it should return True, and it returns False. I don´t understand why

Tags: python

I don´t understand why it returns False, if `sequence[0]` is bigger than `sequence[1]`

```
sequence=[10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

a=any(q for q in range(len(sequence)-1) if sequence[q]>=sequence[q+1])
print(a)
```

It works for the indexes bigger than 0

Comment: You are expecting `any` to return true if its argument is non-empty; that's not what it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that, for this list, `(q for q in range(len(sequence)-1) if sequence[q]>=sequence[q+1])` is `(0)`, and `0` is falsey.

Putting the actual indices into any kind of iterable is a red herring here - and you probably don't realise you're actually doing it. What you want to do is merely check if the predicate `sequence[q]>=sequence[q+1]` is true for any `q`. So do this instead:

```
any(sequence[q]>=sequence[q+1] for q in range(len(sequence)-1))
```

This gives an iterable of booleans, and checks if any are `True` or not.

Answer (score 0):

First remove the `any()` to see what your comprehension actually gives you:

```
[q for q in range(len(sequence)-1) if sequence[q]>=sequence[q+1]]
>>> [0]
```

That is, there is one pair of numbers where the condition is true, and it is at index 0 in the original list.

`any([0])` is then `False` because 0 is false. `any()` checks each item to see whether it's truthy.

Robin's solution is the usual way to do it, by using the comparison result as the yielded value. But it can be quite a lot faster to not yield false values, which you might notice if your sequence is long enough, so you could use this form:

```
any(True for q in range(len(sequence)-1) if sequence[q]>=sequence[q+1])
```